# How to increase Disk Storage in fedora 17?

Tags: linux, storage, fedora

i am using fedora 17 and win7 , now i have about 70 G free space on win7 but just 1 G in linux , total storage for fedora 17 that i allocated was about 15 G , how can i increase it? is there any way to remove linux and get back the 15 G storage and then install it with higher storage?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; this type of question would be better suited to [SU].

Comment: Delete Windows, you'll have _plenty_ of space afterwards. That's what I did when I found out that I hadn't used Windows in almost a year ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into any Linux live CD with a partition editor and resize the partitions. Your Fedora installation disc should come with GParted. (If it doesn't, you can always just `sudo yum install gparted`.)

Comment: i used GParted and created ext4 partition , but how can i link it to my file system? i mean still when i want to install something i get not enough space error...

Comment: Don't create a new partition. Resize your existing partition.